# How to call a component from another when I have an event using Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component for loader, something like this code:
loader.component.ts

```
export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {
    show = false;
    private subscription: Subscription;
    constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.loaderService.loaderState.subscribe(
            (state: LoaderState) => {
                if (state.queue.length > 0) {
                    this.show = true;
                    
                } else {
                    this.show = false;
                }
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
      ///
    }
}
```

I want to call this component from another component:
lang.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   ////
  this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
    if(event.lang){
      console.log(event.lang)
    LoaderComponent  /// I want to call in this case
    }
  });
}
```

Please can you share with me any idea how to call `LoaderCompoent` in `LangCompoent`?

Here is LoaderService:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoaderService {
    private loaderSubject = new Subject<LoaderState>();
    loaderState = this.loaderSubject.asObservable();
    private loaderQueue = new LoaderState();

    constructor() {
    }

    add() {
        this.loaderQueue.queue.push(true);
        this.loaderSubject.next(this.loaderQueue);
    }

    pop() {
        this.loaderQueue.queue.pop();
        this.loaderSubject.next(this.loaderQueue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your current implementation seems like an anti-pattern. I'd suggest you conditionally show/hide the loader component and let it do all its logic within itself. If this is a component you use app-wide, consider placing it on one of the root templates, and using `@Input()` with the loader component to show/hide.

Comment: can you share relevant portion of your loaderService as well

Comment: @shaN I added LoaderService

Comment: if I assume correctly that you want to hide the loader component on LangChangeEvent, you can just call the pop()  function in your service from LangComponent

Comment: I called pop() function but the loader  didn't display. I want to display loader icon when change language (when I have an event). Thanks for you help

Comment: for showing the loader icon, you should call add().